# Developing an Operating System using TDD/BDD

Tags: operating-system, tdd, bdd

I just wonder. Is there anybody in the world, using TDD or BDD to write an OS? And is this even posible? I've tried to google it, but didn't find any kind of information.
So, guys. Is it possible to build an entire OS using TDD? And BDD?

Comment: I *really* doubt that. Its hard enough to even debug kernel coke and that sometimes requires special hardware. But TDD? No.

Comment: @Linuxios You may be unable to test everything in the OS/kernel directly or easily, but this doesn't render TDD impossible for most of the code.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: For drivers? You can. For modules? You can. For code memory management? You'll spend more time writing the code to make it possible than the code itself.

Comment: @Linuxios Who said testing ought to always be easier than writing product code? :) Anyhow, you can test even that. And you can make use of virtualization to get around some testability problems.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: True, true.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use TDD for most of OS development and for most of the code. It may get tricky at certain times/places due to limited testability of low-level, especially CPU/hardware-specific, code. These parts either may receive less direct test coverage (if that's OK) or can be tested in virtual machines or CPU/PC simulators.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. I don't know anyone who is doing it.

As a proof point, I would point out what people are doing with test driven infrastructure with Chef and unit and behavioral testing there. For more info, see [TestKitchen](https://github.com/opscode/test-kitchen) for Chef.